# Running compiled MATLAB from python

Tags: python, matlab

I have some MATLAB script, for example:

```
function mat_foo(varargin)
    params.x = 'aaa';
    params = parse_input(params, varargin);
    disp(params.x);
end
```

`parse_input` is a function I have which convert data from `varargin` and override the defaults at `'params'` struct.

I compiled this function and I want to call it from python, I do it the following way:

```
subprocess.check_call(['$/mat_foo.app/Contents/MacOS/applauncher x bbb'], shell=True)
```

This sets `params.x` to `'bbb'` and works well.

My problem is that each time I want to call a compiled MATLAB it initializes the MCR and takes about 8-10 seconds.
My question is if there is a way to initialize the MCR once and use it many times quickly?
I use MATLAB R2013a and python 2.7.5 on OSX

Comment: I have seen compiled matlab code get called from php without 10 second waiting times at each call. So though I don't know how to achieve it, it must definitely be possible. Just to eliminate the improbable, could you test whether the problem also occurs with a trival function (that you can show here as a reproducible example).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Maybe the code was generated using matlab coder, such code does not require MCR.

Comment: @Daniel The code was compiled by myself, so it definitely requires the MCR. I just don't know the details of how it is called but I think this can be considered proof that it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to compile your code in a shared library as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f2-9676.html). You can load this library in python with

```
mymatlab = cdll.LoadLibrary("mymatlab_library.so")
```

and initialize and load the MCR by calling a function

```
mymatlab.initializeMyLibrary()
```

that might do nothing or only prints a text to the console with matlab's `disp` function.

Subsequent function calls to your library should execute immediately.

See also this [Mathworks discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/306814).